# How to allow custom logo image upload if logo is on home page, not in header?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a web site (a theme) in WordPress with logo which is not in header, but in front-page.php instead. Is there any way to allow user to upload custom logo image instead of the current one? I've seen many tutorials on how to do allow custom header logo upload, but the problem is, my logo needs to be on the page itself, not in header.

Comment: More details please

Comment: Hi, I want to be able to change logo image. The image is currently on home page and I need to make it changeable. Meaning, if I want to put another image instead of the current one, I need to click on the current image and choose from library another one. Maybe to make it as custom post type?

Comment: @Nancy, you have to put your relevant code what you have done so far

Comment: I found the solution myself and answered my own question. Thank you everyone just the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier than I thought. Put the following code to functions.php

```
 function m1_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'm1_logo' ); // Add setting for logo uploader

    // Add control for logo uploader (actual uploader)
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'm1_logo', array(
        'label'    => __( 'Upload Logo (replaces text)', 'm1' ),
        'section'  => 'title_tagline',
        'settings' => 'm1_logo',
    ) ) );
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'm1_customize_register' );
```

That piece of code adds image(logo) uploader to your theme custmozer.

And then put this where you need the image to show:

```
 <img src="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'm1_logo' ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>">
```

Customize to fit your page needs and that's it.